# Off page seo vs on page seo, market samurai competition check

Tags: seo, competitors, market-share

I did a competition check with market samurai on keyword
"really cheap widgets"

The competition result is reflected in the attached image:
[image: market samurai competition search]

They are huge sites but they do not have on page seo for my keyword, no keyword in title, url, desc, heading. They are targeting the most general terms like widgets, and other keywords related to them.
But most are really old domains, thousands of backlinks.

Could this guys be beaten with fewer backlinks but targeted pages with good content, on page seo, etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's only one way to find out... (try)

In theory, if you target specific keywords, there is no reason why you shouldn't be able to complete for them if they've been overlooked by any other websites. That's the whole idea behind the concept of targetting long(er)-tailed keywords.